# Biblatex: Id. in lieu of Ibid.

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I have what I thought would be a very simple question, but has turned out to be much more difficult.

Using biblatex and the verbose-inote style, I would like to redefine for footcite Ibid as *Id.* and print an ibidem citation as follows: "*Id.* at #" where # is the page number.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{letterpaper, margin=1in}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[style=verbose-inote,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\bibliography{nbib.bib}


\begin{document}

This is a test.\footcite[1]{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want to refer back to the last mention of the citation or the first mention? Since you use `inote` wouldn't it be nicer to refer back to the note of the respective citation and not the page number?

Comment: In cases where it's not the immediately preceding citation, yes, that would make sense. The page number I referred to would be the cited page of the source.

Comment: Ahhh, so you simply want "Id. at p. 14" instead of "ibid., p. 14"?

Comment: Yes , that's precisely it.

Answer (score 4):

Changing "ibid." to "id." is as easy as

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  ibidem = {id\adddot},
}
```

(where you of course replace `english` by the language you are actually using).

---

For the "at" only for pages after "id." we can do the following

```
\NewBibliographyString{at}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  ibidem = {id\adddot},
  at = {at},
}
```

and then

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{%
  \ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage\AND\ifpages{#1}}
    {\bibstring{at}%
     \addspace}
    {}%
  #1}

\renewbibmacro*{footcite:ibid}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperlink]{\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}%
  \iffieldpages{postnote}{\printunit{\addspace}}{}%
  \ifloccit
    {\global\toggletrue{cbx:loccit}}
    {}}
```

This tries to make sure no spurious punctuation occurs.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose-inote,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}

\NewBibliographyString{at}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  ibidem = {id\adddot},
  at = {at},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{%
  \ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage\AND\ifpages{#1}}
    {\bibstring{at}%
     \addspace}
    {}%
  #1}

\renewbibmacro*{footcite:ibid}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperlink]{\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}%
  \iffieldpages{postnote}{\printunit{\addspace}}{}%
  \ifloccit
    {\global\toggletrue{cbx:loccit}}
    {}}

\begin{document}
This is a test.\footcite[1]{sigfridsson} Ewoud\footcite[1]{sigfridsson}. Ewoud\footcite[jeugd]{sigfridsson}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is brilliant, many thanks!.

I thought I could also drop the page number prefix in the citations such that it would print something like "Id. at 5" instead of "Id. at p. 5" using the command:

    \DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}%

However, that doesn't seem to work. Thoughts?

Comment: @ssch Do you only want to drop the prefix for the "id." citations or for all? In any case the field to play around with is `postnote`.

Comment: Not just in the Id., but for all citations. Again, many thanks.

Comment: @ssch Then it should be as easy as replacing the `\mkpageprefix[pagination]{#1}` by `#1`. See the edited answer.

Comment: Brilliant. However, using that I'm getting citations that are missing a space, such that it's "Id. at241.", not "Id. at 241"

I fixed by changing that line to   \addspace #1}

Comment: @ssch Ah yes, I have changed the spacing a bit. Try the edited answer.